# 500 error when I add redirect www to my domaine

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I add rewriterule to my .htacces file to add 'www' to my website, now they add www but I get always this error 500

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: You don't need `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` if all you want is to add www

Comment: I remove it but always I get the same error

Comment: And if you also remove `RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|`

Comment: Yes I get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting  a 500 internal server error/infinite loop error because your rule   `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`  rewrites all requests (including `/index.php` ) to `/index.php` . In order to solve this , You need to exclude the Uri you are rewriting to :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
#rewrite all to /index.php excluding `/index.php the destination uri
RewriteCond ℅{REQUEST_URI} !/index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Please check your server error log for info about the error.

Answer (score -1):

You should add an A record with www
The redirect you added is just redirecting your site abc.com to www.abc.com .. but in the backend, on server, www points nowhere.
So you should go to your DNS settings and add an "A" record with domain www , type A record and point to the IP address of your server.
Hope that helps.

Comment: An http status 500 is not the result of a missing DNS resolution.